# How many initial states can an NFA and DFA have?

Tags: automata, dfa, nfa

How many initial states can an NFA and DFA have in Finite Automata theory

Comment: You should ask in https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your definitions. That said, it's hard to imagine any reasonable definition of a DFA in which there is more than one initial state. Why? Well, you'd need a way of telling which state to start in. Typically, only the input string is available to a DFA, and that could be empty. It's easier to imagine an NFA being defined in such a way that multiple initial states are OK. It would be basically equivalent to having a separate initial state with epsilon-transitions to the multiple initial states, and then just simply not showing the "true" initial state. This would be analogous to the way NFAs need not show dead states and can simply crash.

Comment: even I, someone who knows the answer, couldn't follow with your answer easily. You're missing an "only one" somewhere :p

Comment: @mAhMoUdDaFeR I re-read the answer and didn't see anywhere that needed "only one" anywhere. Do you think it would be helpful to add an example maybe? I mean I'm sure it would but if the text were clear enough without it then that could be omitted.

Comment: I mean "it's hard to imagine" and "typically" seem a bit unsure. Since the answer is always only one starting state denoted by q0 (which is a factor in its formal definition) then why not state it directly

Comment: @mAhMoUdDaFeR My point is it's possible to formally define NFAs in such a way that multiple initial states are admissible, but it's probably not possible to do so for DFAs in the same way. To state that NFAs cannot have multiple initial states seems like it's simply incorrect. It would be more correct to say that formal definitions I've seen have not attempted to do so, but that's not what is being asked.

Comment: would you say that epsilon NFAs can have multiple starting states?

Answer (score 0):

As per the definition of DFA, so as NFA  it can have only one initial state. 
See the definition [here](https://www.udemy.com/course/introduction-to-theory-of-computations/learn/lecture/15569126/?instructorPreviewMode=student_v4#overview).